# Is it possible to discover plugged disks from Java?

Tags: java, io, disk, web-crawler, discovery

I'm writing a disk crawler and if the user doesn't provide an existing path the program should search all disks that are available. Does anybody know is it possible and if it is how to do that from Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
File.listRoots();
```

Answer (score 1):

Only works on windows, on unix based operating system you will have 1 root, independent of the number of disks.